# Why is the new (reloaded) profile page no longer available?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

I just checked the [reloaded profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/reloaded/current).

But the reloaded version of profile page is no longer available; I am getting a Page Not Found error.

I liked the reloaded version. Where did it go?

Comment: See also [Profile Page Makeover, Part 2: the Prototype](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231112/171881).

Comment: So, Can it be possible , it's under development, so they removed it for now?

Comment: That is possible, but there is no hint on that question that this feature was removed.

Comment: "Page not found" error cant be considered as a hint of removal ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is a work in progress.

There are other, related changes being worked on in the mean time (essentially, everything on the current profile page that isn't on the reloaded profile itself).

Removing the page while these were being finalized made sense (in particular given that the Reloaded profile was not finalized/complete/production ready).

Comment: Can I ask for a particular date or time when it'll be released ? ^_^

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - 6-8 weeks. But joking aside - there are a few features that are still in early design phase, so... yeah.

Comment: Alright! Still waiting for 6-8 weeks time longer to me T_T. But I can wait for this cool UI. hehe B-)

Comment: For those that don't catch the reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/181683

Comment: Yay!  I had this same question a few days ago and figured you guys decided not to go with the reloaded profiles.  They're very nice looking.